# How to solve the error undefined the function or variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

This is the code I write in Matlab. As you can see, I have defined the symbolic variable `tao`. However, it still shows that undefined variable or functions. I didn't know where is wrong in the code.
The function is like this:

[image: this is the function form]

```
Ch = 0.8;  H=0.6088;
syms t u s k tao
fsb= limit( symsum( (int( Ch*s^(1/2)*int((u-s)^(H-3/2)*u^(H-1/2),u,floor(t/tao)*tao,floor((t+tao)/tao)*tao),s,(k-1)*tao,k*tao ))^2,k,1,floor(t/tao)),tao,0) + ...
+limit( (int( Ch*s^(1/2)*int((u-s)^(H-3/2)*u^(H-1/2),u,s,floor((t+tao)/tao)*tao ),s,floor(t/tao)*tao,floor((t+tao)/tao)*tao) )^2,tao , 0);
fsb = matlabFunction(fsb);
sss=fsb(1);
```

I have tried change the path into the Matlab installed path, but it didn't work.

The `fsb` is a function defined by my self. It's a complicated function including integral and limit.

This is the information about the error:

```
undefined functions or variables 'tao'        
symengine>@(t)limit(integral(@(s)sqrt(s).*integral(@(u)u.^(6.8e1./6.25e2).*1.0./(-s+u).^(5.57e2./6.25e2),s,tao.*floor((t+tao)./tao)).*(4.0./5.0),tao.*floor(t./tao),tao.*floor((t+tao)./tao)).^2,tao==0.0)+limit(symsum(integral(@(s)sqrt(s).*integral(@(u)u.^(6.8e1./6.25e2).*1.0./(-s+u).^(5.57e2./6.25e2),tao.*floor(t./tao),tao.*floor((t+tao)./tao)).*(4.0./5.0),tao.*(k-1.0),k.*tao).^2,k,1.0,floor(t./tao)),tao==0.0,Real)
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the full error message. Also read [mre], if we cannot reproduce the error, it is much less likely that we can help you.

Comment: check your parentheses in the code.

Comment: @Cris Luengo:I have changed the code,I think  you can reproduce the example now.

Comment: @Navid: I have checked the parentheses in the code. I think it's right now

Comment: But that is not the full error message. MATLAB always explains where in the code the error happens. Or are you typing in these commands one by one? Is it the last line that produces the error?

Comment: I did notice that you have 5 variables in your function, but only assign a value to one (and it’s unclear which one that is). The other variables will obviously be undefined.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: In order to explain my problem ,I post a picture link about the function. As you can see, there is only one variable 'tau'  in the function. 'tao'  represent 'tau' in the code. And I use 'k' to represent 'i' in the code.  It's the first time that I use the website, so if there is any unclear expression,please forgive me.

Comment: But there’s also a `t` in your function. Maybe one variable is there by accident, because one bracket is in the wrong place or something like that. This sort of mistake is easy to make, your expression is way too complex. I recommend that you build up your function by making smaller parts first, and then combing those into the larger expression.

Comment: @Cris Luengo:And I have a question : according to the integral expression, the symbolic variable 'u' and 's' should be replaced by 't' and 'tao', that is to say: it only contains the 't' and 'tao' in the expression. However, there still is the 'u' and 's' in the wrong information and the transformed function named 'fsb'. I think the int function didn't work in the code. Can I say like this?

Comment: I tried running the function, but it takes for ever, it's still not done. So it's hard to help you here. It looks like the `limit` function is not removing the `tao` variable from `fbs`, there should be only the `t` variable left, according to the image you posted.

Comment: I think `limit` might not be able to find the limit, and therefore the `tao` variable is not removed. With a simpler expression, `limit` produces a symbolic expression without the limit variable.

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Thank you anyway